# Rails Console - ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, activerecord, console

I am trying to delete a mass amount of records from my database. My destroy_all keeps getting stopped when a callback fails to destroy a record because of `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. I want to skip the callbacks when the error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` occurs on records that the callback is trying to delete.

All User records belong to school via a UserSchool relation. I am trying to delete all User Records where the `school_id`: 74 is present in any UserSchool record.

```
user_ids = UserSchool.where(school_id: 74).map(&:user_id)
User.where(id: user_ids).destroy_all
```

The result is:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=17
```

I want to skip over that error and continue destroying User records. How can I rescue here?

Comment: The error message seems to be not related with the query you are doing. Are you sure you posted the right code?

Comment: The only way you would get that error is if you either a) have a dependent destroy on comments. If this is the case, you could remove it and delete the records. Or b) you have added some validation after an invalid record is in your database in which you would get this error for multiple requests.

Answer (score 1):

```
user_ids = UserSchool.where(school_id: 74).map(&:user_id)
users = User.where(id: user_ids)

users.each do |user|
  begin 
    user.destroy
  rescue => ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    puts "Record not found"
  end
end
```

Comment: that skips all callbacks, I just want to skip the ones that return ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think we can rescue by looping it over each object.

```
user_ids.each do |user_id|
 User.find(user_id).destroy rescue nil
end
```

For only `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception you could do,

```
user_ids.each do |user_id|
  begin 
    Contact.find(user_id).destroy
  rescue => ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    puts "Record not found"
  end
end
```